# Visual Studio 2017 C++ Exe for any pc (linking vcruntime140.dll)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface

I'm very new to GUI programming in c++, thus I don't have that much experience.

I created myself a GUI for my programm using the Visual Studio 2017 CRL package and now I'm trying to make this exe available for everyone.
The application works fine for those who have Visual Studio or VC Runtime installed but for those who don't the programm throws something like: "vcruntime140.dll is missing on your computer to run this app".
I am not sure how to link these dll's in my programm so that EVERYONE is able to use it.
I'm also not quit sure how I would link dll's.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the structure of C++/CLI looks different to traditional C++. I just picked it because I didn't really know how to create a good looking GUI. Maybe I should try building my GUI from scratch without this tool.

Answer (score 10):

There's basically two options.

The Standard in the industry is to ship the Visual Studio 20xx Runtime Redistributable Installer alongside your program, and have it run before anyone tries to run your program themselves, to make sure that the .dll files are installed onto the target computer.

The other option is to change the way that the libraries are linked to the executable at compile-time. This is done with a flag in Visual Studio:

[image: Property Pages]

Basically, you want to change the **Runtime Library** field to either say *Multi-Threaded* or *Multi-Threaded Debug* depending on whether you're in Release or Debug mode, as opposed to "Multi-Threaded DLL", which is the default.

Note, however, that you need to make sure that every single library you're using was compiled the same way: if any of them were compiled using the DLL version of the Runtime Library, they'll interoperate with your code in funny ways, and the least of your problems will be that they'll need the DLLs installed anyways, defeating your effort.

Naturally, that's not an issue if all your libraries are Header-Only, but if any of them have been compiled, then you'll need to recompile them using the correct settings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Visual Studio 2017 redistribuables on the machine (that's how it works for every version of Visual Studio).

However, I could not find any official link on Microsoft website (probably because this is not officially released yet)....

You probably need to use 2015 version (for which redistribuables are available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)) and wait for 2017 to become an official release.